# Are USB cables active circuits?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

I always assumed a USB cable between two devices is just a collection of wires. I recently saw some pictures when shopping for cables indicating they have internal circuitry.

Could someone clarify if USB3.0 cables are only wiring or is there an active device within the A end?

Comment: Which kind of USB3 cables or what internal circuitry you mean? There are many kinds of USB3 cables.

Comment: Some USB-C cables have identification chips in them so that the connected devices can determine if the cable is meant for high power (>3A).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by usb cable.

Standard USB A/B cables, no they should just be wires. USB C to USB A/B cables can have resistors for signaling for power. USB C with high current carrying capabilites have EMark circuits to enable the high current capabilities.

There are any number of non-standard cables that have built in circuits as well. Usb to USB network cables, or USB cables with leds or lighting, for example.

Comment: There are also active USB extension cable that are able to exceed the maximum cable length.